# Where do I put html template for Angular UI Modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the Angular UI modal with a custom template. Whenever I try to click it, I get an angular error that it cannot find the template. Right not I have the controller file and template html file in the same folder. What path do I use to access the html template for the modal?

Comment: For a relative path, the one from your `index.html` file or from the `<base>` tag if you're using one. Alternatively, use an absolute path

Comment: May be add the folder structure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the path based on the root of your app.

For example if your root is '/app' and your template is in '/app/view/templates' then your path would be 'view/templates'.

> template: "view/template.html"

To confirm the issue is related to your path, you can try setting template, and if it works you know it's a path problem.

> template: "I can see this!"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your folder structure is as follows and `js` is the root of application:

```
app
  js
    main.js
    modal
       template.html
       modal.controller.js
  styles
  images
```

Then your template path would be:

```
templateUrl: "modal/template.html"
```

Here is a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gjd1m2OINLRvSFUSHCs3?p=preview)